# Powerpoint Office Web App Resolution

Tags: office-web-apps, powerpoint-services

The resolution of the slide show in the Powerpoint Office Web App seems to have been lowered. Propably to reduce latency and bandwith usage over the network.

I am wondering if it possible to tune the resolution/graphic display option so that the slide show is displayed more nicely.

In Central Admin > Service Application >  Powerpoint Viewing Service I found some options but none for adjusting such a setting.

But maybe it is not possible at all to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't any configuration options for this.  If you need it to display better, you would need to actually open it in PowerPoint rather than the web viewer.

Comment: Ok, that's what I also thought. Well, it isn't as if the lowered resolution is that bad.